# How to distinguish registration by property name in autofac aggregate service?

Tags: state, autofac

```
interface IState {

}

class GoodState: IState {}
class BadState: IState {}
class MoreState: IState {}

// I stuck at here... :(
interface StateAggregateService {
  IState GoodState {get;}
  IState BadState {get;}
  IState MoreState {get;}
}
```

Basically, I want to implement the State Machine pattern. I want to use the **autofac aggregate service** extension to create a factory class for me automatically. But all the concrete state classes inherit from the `IState` interface, the aggregate service extension cannot distinguish them.

One walkaround is to define some dummy interface like `IGoodState` which inherits from `IState`. The problem is that as the number of state classes increase, so do the number of dummy interfaces, and I feel it is really a dumb idea.

Is there's a way to associate registration with the property name, or something like that?

Comment: Keyed registration seems the solution for given problem. Refer the link https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html for more details.

Comment: No. The `AggregatedService` does not respect the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use **Named** registration for your `IState` implementation and use **property injection** for the class implementing `IStateAggregateService`. So for aggregate service you would have:

```
interface IStateAggregateService
{
    IState GoodState { get; }
    IState BadState { get; }
    IState MoreState { get; }
}

class StateAggregateService : IStateAggregateService
{
    public IState GoodState { get; set; }
    public IState BadState { get; set; }
    public IState MoreState { get; set; }
}
```

and the registration would look like the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<GoodState>().Named<IState>("GoodState");
builder.RegisterType<BadState>().Named<IState>("BadState");
builder.RegisterType<MoreState>().Named<IState>("MoreState");

builder.Register(c => new StateAggregateService
    {
        GoodState = c.ResolveNamed<IState>("GoodState"),
        BadState = c.ResolveNamed<IState>("BadState"),
        MoreState = c.ResolveNamed<IState>("MoreState")
    }).As<IStateAggregateService>();
```

Keep in mind this approach would return the same object every time you call a property from aggregate service.

If you want fresh instance every time you call a property, you could use different approach with **keyed registration** and `IIndex<TKey, TService>` interface; the registration would look like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<GoodState>().Keyed<IState>("GoodState");
builder.RegisterType<BadState>().Keyed<IState>("BadState");
builder.RegisterType<MoreState>().Keyed<IState>("MoreState");

builder.RegisterType<StateAggregateService>().As<IStateAggregateService>();
```

and implementation of the service

```
class StateAggregateService : IStateAggregateService
{
    private readonly IIndex<string, IState> _states;

    public IState GoodState => _states["GoodState"];
    public IState BadState => _states["BadState"];
    public IState MoreState => _states["MoreState"];

    public StateAggregateService(IIndex<string, IState> states)
    {
        _states = states;
    }
}
```

To make this approach cleaner, you might want to use some enum as a key for your `IState` implementations instead of `string`.

Also, you could just get rid of `StateAggregateService` and use `IIndex<TKey, TService>` as a factory wherever you need.

**Updated:**
As stated in comment, it's true, the solution you need is not possible to be achieved with Aggregated Service. But it's possible to do something similar with some manual registration and reflection. For the following interface and aggregator class:

```
interface IStateAggregateService
{
    IState GoodState { get; }
    IState BadState { get; }
    IState MoreState { get; }
}

class StateAggregateService : IStateAggregateService
{
    public IState GoodState { get; set; }
    public IState BadState { get; set; }
    public IState MoreState { get; set; }
}
```

you could use the following registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<GoodState>().Keyed<IState>("GoodState");
builder.RegisterType<BadState>().Keyed<IState>("BadState");
builder.RegisterType<MoreState>().Keyed<IState>("MoreState");

builder.Register(c =>
    {
        var serviceProps = typeof(StateAggregateService).GetProperties();

        var service = new StateAggregateService();
        foreach (var property in serviceProps)
        {
            property.SetValue(service, c.ResolveKeyed<IState>(property.Name));
        }

        return service;
    }).As<IStateAggregateService>();
```

The difference is you need to create a class implementing your aggregation interface. This solution uses properties names so you need to keep their names the same as types, or prepare your own logic to assign proper implementation to aggregator properties.

Comment: But this defies the use of the `Aggregated Service`. I just reviewed the implementation of the Aggregated Service, and I found it does not read any key, name or attribute at all. :(

Comment: @davidshen84 you are right, I took a look at the implemetation of Aggregated Service on GitHub and it is not possible to achive what you want. But it is possible to have something similar, maybe it would be "good enough" for you - I have updated my answer with another solution